# How to make row 1 as variable with SAS coding (No proc SQL )

Tags: sas, var, proc

After importing a dataset from excel with proc import, I also used getnames.
This is the table I got,

```
    A             B           C          D               E    
Black Coal    Oil Source   Biomass    Wind Source    Solar PV
```

I want to make the 2nd row (black coal, oil source, biomass, wind source, solar PV) as variable and also remove the spaces with (_). Can anyone please help me by writing the code.

I hope I will get a direct answer with codes.

Comment: Are you saying the first row in the Excel sheet has the strings 'A','B','C',etc? Or that the first row has the names 'Black Coal','Oil Source'?  That is that there is some extra row before the start of the actual table in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine.  The column labels will have spaces, and the column name will have underscores.  This is normal and not a problem.

```
proc import datafile='c:/downloads/energy.xlsx' dbms=xlsx replace out=energy;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the VALIDVARNAME option to V7 then SAS will convert the strings in the first row into valid SAS names (if it can).  The original string will be used as the variable labels.

```
 options validvarname=v7;
 proc import file='myfile.xslx' dbsm=xlsx out=want replace;
 run;
```

If the first row of the spreadsheet does not contain the column headers then use the RANGE statement to tell it to start reading from the second row (or wherever the header row actually is).

```
 options validvarname=v7;
 proc import file='myfile.xslx' dbsm=xlsx out=want replace;
   range='$A2:';
 run;
```